# Iterating over Service Fabric Actors throws InvalidCastException

Tags: azure-service-fabric, stateful-actor-service

I am using the FabricClient QueryManager to iterate over all partitions to find all actors and return a list.  This works fine on my local cluster but throws InvalidCastException when running in our Azure sandbox.  Specifically, `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Fabric.SingletonPartitionInformation' to type 'System.Fabric.Int64RangePartitionInformation'."`

```
public async Task<List<Store>> GetStores()
{
    var cancelToken = new CancellationToken(false);
    var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
    var actorServiceUri = new ServiceUriBuilder("StoreActorService").ToUri();
    var partitions = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetPartitionListAsync(actorServiceUri);

    var actorIds = new List<ActorId>();
    foreach (var partition in partitions)
    {
        // the following cast works locally but throws InvalidCast in our Azure sandbox
        var partitionInfo = (Int64RangePartitionInformation)partition.PartitionInformation;

        var actorServiceProxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(
            actorServiceUri, 
            partitionInfo.LowKey);

        var continueToken = (ContinuationToken)null;
        do
        {
            var page = await actorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync(continueToken, cancelToken);
            actorIds.AddRange(page.Items.Select(actor => actor.ActorId));
            continueToken = page.ContinuationToken;
        } while (continueToken != null);
    }

    var stores = new List<Store>();
    foreach (var actorId in actorIds)
    {
        var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IStoreActor>(actorId, actorServiceUri);
        var store = await proxy.RetrieveAsync(actorId.ToString());
        stores.Add(store);
    }
    return stores;
}
```

As shown in Service Fabric Explorer, the service is partitioned for `Int64Range` as required.
[image]

Any thoughts on why Azure thinks it's a `SingletonPartition`?

Thanks.
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that somehow this Actor Service did get created in a Singleton Partition in our Sandbox environment, but not in either local or production environments.  I didn't think this was possible, but I guess it is.